# Detecting local IP address under FireMonkey3

Tags: delphi, firemonkey-fm3, wsastartup

Need to detect local IP address under FireMonkey3. In VCL version, I have been using unit **WinSock** with methods for it

```
WSAStartup(...)
gethostname(...)
```

**One limitation:** don't need to use any third-party library. I am porting ASTA components to FireMonkey3 platform, and don't want to do dependencies among components.

Answer (score 9):

If you need a cross-platform solution try using Indy and the `TIdStack.AddLocalAddressesToList` method included in the `IdStack` unit

Try this sample

```
var
  AAddresses: TStrings;
begin
  AAddresses := TStringList.Create;
  try
    TIdStack.IncUsage;
    try
      GStack.AddLocalAddressesToList(AAddresses);
    finally
      TIdStack.DecUsage;
    end;
    if AAddresses.Count > 0 then
      //do something
  finally
    AAddresses.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you do not have any Indy components instantiated at the time, you will have to manually call `TIdStack.IncUsage()` to ensure the `GStack` pointer is valid before using it, then call `TIdStack.DecUsage()` when you are done with it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this return just 127.0.0.1 for me on sdk and mobile device but i have access to web via wifi...

Comment: @peimanF.: are you using Android? `AddLocalAddressesToList()` has not been implemented on Android yet, but should work on iOS.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes im using android.answer mentioned as `cross-platform`.how ever what is your suggestion for android!?

Comment: @peimanF. You will likely have to use Embarcadero's Android JNI Bridge framework to access Android's Java APIs directly, specifically either the `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` and `NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()` methods, or the `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()` method.